# Function call from js script in ejs file tags

Tags: javascript, ejs

Suppose an ejs file for upvoting system:

```
<% if(clicked(post_id)==1) %>
    // load green button 
<%} else {%>
     // load red button

 <script>
 function clicked(id){
   if(currentUser.upvotes_downvotes===undefined)
       return -1;
   PreClicked = arr.find(clicked => {
        return clicked.postId.equals(id);})
   if(PreClicked === undefined)
    return 0;
   else if(PreClicked.type === "upvote")
     return 1;
   else if(PreClicked.type === "downvote")
     return 2;
     }
   </script>
```

But I am getting clicked() is not defined

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry, how is this related to mongodb?

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the tag.